# mod_rewrite wrong behaviour when face with mkdir in url

Tags: .htaccess, question2answer

I have a Q2A website and use this `.htaccess`:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?qa-rewrite=$0&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
</IfModule>
```

now, when I request `example.com/1/mkdir` url, `506.shml` is generated for `qa-rewrite` parameter. This happens only for mkdir and for other words it's ok.

Comment: "&%{QUERY_STRING}"? What's wrong with QSA?

Comment: I have no professions for PCRE and mod-rewrite. I know that question pages in Q2A have `domain.ltd/{id}/{title}` format. I copied this .htaccess content from their forum. Could you be more descriptive please? (specially about QSA)

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa

Comment: I replaced last rule with `RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?qa-rewrite=$0 [L,QSA]`. Is it true? this problem take place only when word `mkdir` is used in url.

Comment: Did you try looking outside the actual web server, at any security layers? Sounds like someone implemented security-by-paranoia.

Comment: Not yet. Then isn't .htaccess content the reason?

Comment: It's not in what you've shown there.